# Nested set categories, visibility

Tags: mysql, sql, nested, nested-sets

I have two tables pages and pages_to_menu, the second one keeps the nested data for the menu, they look like this:

```
 pages : ID | Title | Published
        ----------------------
         1     P1      1
         2     P2      0
         3     P2.1    1
         4     P2.2    1

 pages_to_menu:
         ID | lft | rgt | level | page_id | parent_id
         ---------------------------------------------
          1    1     10     0        0         0
          2    2     3      1        1         1
          3    4     9      1        2         1
          4    5     6      2        3         3
          5    7     8      2        4         3
```

so when I execute this query I'm able to get whole tree:

```
SELECT node.level, node.page_id, page.title
FROM 
        pages_to_menu AS node
        Left Join pages as page on page.id = node.page_id
        ,
        pages_to_menu AS parent
WHERE 
        node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt  

GROUP BY node.id
ORDER BY node.lft
```

Shows this:

```
  level | page_id | Title
  ------------------------
   0          0       Null
   1          1       P1
   1          2       P2
   2          3       P2.1
   2          4       P2.2
```

The problem is that P2 is published = 0 so P2 and all it's children, P2.1, P2.2 have to be hidden

the right output must be

```
  level | page_id | Title
  ------------------------
   0          0       Null
   1          1       P1
```

I tried with

```
SELECT node.level, node.page_id, page.title
FROM 
        pages_to_menu AS node 
        ,
        pages_to_menu AS parent
        INNER Join pages as page on page.id = parent.page_id  AND page.published = 1
WHERE 
        node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt  

GROUP BY node.id
ORDER BY node.lft
```

But this effects only the parent node

```
  level | page_id | Title
  ------------------------
   0          0       Null
   1          1       P1 
   2          3       P2.1
   2          4       P2.2
```

P2.1 and P2.2 are still there.

Sorry if my English is a bit bad, and thank you in advanced for any help!

Comment: Will your hierarchy go deeper than two levels you show? Like `P2.1.1` and such?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Yes probably it will go I'm trying to make it to work with unlimited sub categories.

Comment: Will `P2.1.1` still look at `P2`'s `Published` flag?

Comment: Yes, P2 -> P2.1 -> P2.2 -> P2.3 if P2 is off all branch must be off

Comment: If you haven't done so already you might want to look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1042206/2055998).

Comment: Is there any field in your table that tells, a page record belongs to which record ? Example: P2.1 and P2.2 belongs to P2.

Comment: this is done by lft and rgt attr you can see that P2 has lft=4 and rgt9, so all between like 5 - 6 and 7 - 8 are children of P2